# neo4j apoc merge node from json file

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I use neo4j apoc tool to load data from  json file which is stored on hdfs , example of the file content like this :

```
{"id":"572911761","label":"Label1","nickName":"xxx","screenName":"xxx","userType":2}
{"id":"111117971217247","label2":"Label","nickName":"dada","userType":2}
{"id":"111112559184932","label3":"Label","nickName":"Kwok","screenName":"kwok","userType":2}
{"id":"1447694416","label":"Label4","nickName":"Sylar","screenName":"sylar","userType":2}
{"id":"111111154273959","label":"Label2","nickName":"Chan","screenName":"kmuhk","userType":2}
```

The Field of `label` is the  `label of node in neo4j`, means I want set Dynamic Label by read Label from the file per line ,  my input cypher is :

```
CALL apoc.load.json("hdfs://hdp1:8020/apoc/graph/apoc_graph_20200422202753_0_nodes") yield value 
call apoc.merge.node(value.label, {uid:value.uid}, {nickname:value.nickName,screen_name: value.screenName })
```

and it execute error, the error :

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 2, column 1 (offset: 98))
"call apoc.merge.node(value.label, {uid:value.uid}, {nickname:value.nickName,screen_name: value.screenName })"
 ^
```

Ask for help, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty helpful here, it's saying that the last line of your query must either be some kind of update to the graph (like a `CREATE` or a `MERGE`), or otherwise a `RETURN` statement. Here, we've got a `CALL`.

To fix, we want to yield the merged node from `apoc.merge.node`, then return it:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("hdfs://hdp1:8020/apoc/graph/apoc_graph_20200422202753_0_nodes") yield value 
CALL apoc.merge.node(value.label, {uid:value.uid}, {nickname:value.nickName,screen_name: value.screenName }) YIELD node
RETURN node
```